# Python i18n with gettext not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, internationalization, gettext

I tried to look at the python docs about making some i18n mechanism on a python project. Although I usually like python docs, this section didn't look intuitive to me, and I looked another resources. By looking these:

[inventwithpython.com/blog/translate-your-python-3-program-with-the-gettext-module/](https://inventwithpython.com/blog/2014/12/20/translate-your-python-3-program-with-the-gettext-module/)

[Python docs: localizing-your-application](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html#localizing-your-application)

I managed to do the source code I pasted below. First it was giving a domain error, but after adding the .mo files, now it doesn't work or show any error.

**main.py**

```
from gettext import translation
from gettext import gettext as _

lang1 = translation('poker', '/home/myUser/myProjects/pokerProject/resources/localedir', languages=['en'])
lang2 = translation('poker', '/home/myUser/myProjects/pokerProject/resources/localedir', languages=['es'])

lang2.install()

# Code with strings in this way 
print(_('This should be translated'))
```

**.mo file sample**

```
"Generated-By: pygettext.py 1.5\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 2.0.1\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"

#: main.py:26
msgid "This should be translated"
msgstr "Translated text"
```

**Layout (pokerProject sub-tree)**

```
.
├── martintc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── poker
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── model
│           ├── diceset.py
│           ├── die.py
│           ├── errors.py
│           ├── __init__.py
│           ├── main.py
│           ├── poker.pot
│           └── utils.py
└── resources
    └── localedir
        ├── en
        │   └── LC_MESSAGES
        │       ├── poker.mo
        │       └── poker.po
        └── es
            └── LC_MESSAGES
                ├── poker.mo
                └── poker.po
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem and a provisional but not satisfactory solution.

My code had the line:

```
from gettext import gettext as _
```

and it was not needed. As a matter of fact, when I deleted this line, everything went perfectly.

I don't understand well why, but this solved it. I don't know if this will work when I will have another classes with i18n strings

Comment: Here is why:
"For convenience, you want the _() function to be installed in Python’s builtins namespace, so it is easily accessible in all modules of your application."
https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html#gettext.install